# grails test url parameters

Tags: url, grails, testing, mapping

Given this mapping:

```
"/student/degree/$studentid/$degreecode"(controller:'student', action:'degree')
```

I am trying the tests below and both fail with `AssertionFailedError: '...did not match any mapping'` and both are valid URLs that do function. I can succeed with a test URL of just '/student/degree' which I think should fail as the parameters are required.

It seems the `assertURL` methods are not handling multiple parameters. Does this only work for 'id' and is it not possible to create tests for these URLs?

```
@TestFor(UrlMappings)
@Mock([StudentController])
class UrlMappingsTests {
    void testUrlMappings() {
        assertForwardUrlMapping("/student/degree/102345678/N", controller: "student", action: "degree") {
            assertForwardUrlMapping("/student/degree/102345678/N", controller: "student", action: "degree") {
                studentid = 102345678
                degreecode = "N"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested with Grails 2.2.4, and it works for me, I just add a custom mappings class:

```
package test

class MyUrlMappings {
  static mappings = {
    "/test/show/$myId/$myVal"(controller: "test", action: "show")
  }
}

import spock.lang.*
import test.MyUrlMappings

@TestFor(MyUrlMappings)
@Mock([TestController])
//I'm using Spock
class MyUrlMappingsSpec extends Specification {

  void "mapping should consider myId and myVal"() {
    expect:
      assertForwardUrlMapping("/test/show/1/tst", controller: "test", action: "show") {
        //all params considered as String
        myId = '1'
        myVal = 'tst'
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: @dmahapatro Thanks for the edit. I actually tested this before posting and not needed the `extends Specification`.

Comment: Will the test case understand what `expect:` is if it does not inherit from `Specification`? That was my thinking, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @dmahapatro Right, I see now. It works because `assertForwardUrlMapping` will throw an error. Thanks for pointing it :-)

Comment: Glad I made some sense of what I was thinking. ;) Thanks for the fb.